# Click to show multiple element ref by id using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Click to show multiple element ref by id using javascript

This is my code, click link `CLICK HERE` for show elements.

On first click `CLICK HERE` i want to show `one` and `111` (it's same id number `show_1`)

And second click `CLICK HERE` i want to show `two` and `222` (it's same id number `show_2`)

And third click `CLICK HERE` i want to show `three` and `333` (it's same id number `show_3`)

And fourth click `CLICK HERE` i want to show `four` and `444` (it's same id number `show_4`)

And fifth click `CLICK HERE` i want to show `five` and `555` (it's same id number `show_5`)

But when i test my code, it's not work good.  It's show only

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

How can i do that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/x53eh96o/12/

```
<style type="text/css">
    div{
    display: none;
}
</style>
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style=" width: 17%; "> 
      <div id="show_1">one</div>
      <div id="show_2">two</div>
      <div id="show_3">three</div>
      <div id="show_4">four</div>
      <div id="show_5">five</div>
    </td>   
    <td valign="top" style=" width: 17%; "> 
      <div id="show_1">111</div>
      <div id="show_2">222</div>
      <div id="show_3">333</div>
      <div id="show_4">444</div>
      <div id="show_5">555</div>
    </td> 
  </tr>       
<tbody>      
</table>     
<div id="test_link" onclick="myFunction()" style="display: block;">CLICK HERE</div>


<script>
    var show = 0;
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById('show_' + (show += 1)).style.display = "block";    
        if(show == "5")
        {
            document.getElementById("test_link").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Id should be unique. :\

Comment: Yes, by HTML conventions `id` attribute should be unique for webpage. You can use `class` attribute for your needs.

Comment: As above. Just because you want to call 2 elements at the same time, you cannot do it by making both elements having the same element id.

Comment: You can use jquery instead of javascript to get the accurate result. I have solution with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `id` should be unique, so you need to use `class` instead. Now for getting dom element by class name use **[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**, which returns array of dom objects.

```js
var show = 0;

function myFunction() {
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName('show_' + (++show))
  div[0].style.display = "block";
  div[1].style.display = "block";

  if (show == "5") {
    document.getElementById("test_link").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" style=" width: 17%; ">
        <div class="show_1">one</div>
        <div class="show_2">two</div>
        <div class="show_3">three</div>
        <div class="show_4">four</div>
        <div class="show_5">five</div>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style=" width: 17%; ">
        <div class="show_1">111</div>
        <div class="show_2">222</div>
        <div class="show_3">333</div>
        <div class="show_4">444</div>
        <div class="show_5">555</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
<div id="test_link" onclick="myFunction()" style="display: block;">CLICK HERE</div>
```

Using jQuery

```js
var show = 0;

$("#test_link").click(function() {
  $('.show_' + (++show)).css('display','block');
  if (show == 5)
    $(this).css('display','none');
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" style=" width: 17%; ">
        <div class="show_1">one</div>
        <div class="show_2">two</div>
        <div class="show_3">three</div>
        <div class="show_4">four</div>
        <div class="show_5">five</div>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style=" width: 17%; ">
        <div class="show_1">111</div>
        <div class="show_2">222</div>
        <div class="show_3">333</div>
        <div class="show_4">444</div>
        <div class="show_5">555</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
<div id="test_link" style="display: block;">CLICK HERE</div>
```

Comment: -   THANK YOU  ^____^

Comment: @robertqewerutiyo : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style=" width: 17%; "> 
      <div id="show_1" name="show_1">one</div>
      <div id="show_2">two</div>
      <div id="show_3">three</div>
      <div id="show_4">four</div>
      <div id="show_5">five</div>
    </td>   
    <td valign="top" style=" width: 17%; "> 
      <div id="show_1" name="show_1">111</div>
      <div id="show_2">222</div>
      <div id="show_3">333</div>
      <div id="show_4">444</div>
      <div id="show_5">555</div>
    </td> 
  </tr>       
<tbody>      
</table>     
<div id="test_link" onclick="myFunction()" style="display: block;">CLICK HERE</div>


<script>
    var show = 0;
    function myFunction() {
       document.getElementsByName("show_1")[0].style.display="block";
      document.getElementsByName("show_1")[1].style.display="block";

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getElementsByClassName()` any loop through each element.

```css
div {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style=" width: 17%; ">
                <div class="show_1">one</div>
                <div class="show_2">two</div>
                <div class="show_3">three</div>
                <div class="show_4">four</div>
                <div class="show_5">five</div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style=" width: 17%; ">
                <div class="show_1">111</div>
                <div class="show_2">222</div>
                <div class="show_3">333</div>
                <div class="show_4">444</div>
                <div class="show_5">555</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
</table>
<div id="test_link" onclick="myFunction()" style="display: block;">CLICK HERE</div>
<script>
    var show = 0;

    function myFunction() {
        //document.getElementsByClassName('show_' + (show += 1)).style.display = "block";
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('show_' + (show += 1))
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].style.display = "block";
        }
        if (show == "5") {
            document.getElementById("test_link").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```